# PHP fsockopen post redirect issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, sockets, post, fsockopen

I want to use fsockopen in my script to pass some post data to another php script on my server. I've already tested it and it is pretty simple to implement unless you have a routing on your website.

Here is my working example (w/o routing on the server):

**socket_post.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$fp = fsockopen('example.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$vars = array(
   'filename' => 'article.txt',
   'data' => 'Hello world'
);

$content = http_build_query($vars);

fwrite($fp, "POST /sockets/receive_data.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Host: example.com\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "\r\n");

fwrite($fp, $content);
//fclose($fp); // Closes socket immediately without waiting for response
//echo "Done\r\n";

while (!feof($fp)) {
   echo fgets($fp, 1024);
}
```

**receive_data.php**

```
<?php

extract($_POST);
sleep(10);
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

So, it works fine on my testing server, but when I'am trying to implement this script with OpenCart CMS it fails due to the OpenCart's controller routing.

This is a version of a script for OpenCart:

**socket_post.php**

```
<?php
class ControllerSocketsSocketPost extends Controller {
   public function index() {
      header('Content-type: text/plain');

      $fp = fsockopen("example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

      $vars = array(
         'filename' => 'article.txt',
         'data' => 'Hello world'
      );

      $content = http_build_query($vars);

      fwrite($fp, "POST https://example.com/index.php?route=sockets/receive_data HTTP/1.1\r\n"); // !!!THE MAIN PROBLEM HERE!!!
      fwrite($fp, "Host: example.com\r\n");
      fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
      fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n");
      fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
      fwrite($fp, "\r\n");

      fwrite($fp, $content);

      //fclose($fp); // Closes socket immediately without waiting for response
      //echo 'Done';

      while (!feof($fp)) {
         echo fgets($fp, 1024);
      }
   }
}
```

**receive_data.php**

```
<?php
class ControllerSocketsReceiveData extends Controller {
   public function index() {
      extract($this->request->post);
      sleep(10);
      file_put_contents($filename, $data);
   }
}
```

As a result it should create `"article.txt"` file in the same directory and render `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` status on the page, but it gets `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` status due to the routing and html output `<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.example.com/index.php?route=sockets/receive_data">here</a>.</p>`.

How to handle OpenCart's routing in this case? Any advice will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you using apache for opencart ?

Comment: Yes, Apache 2.2.31, PHP 5.3.29

Comment: In the POST URL use the php filepath directly ie /server/xxx/filename.php

Comment: I've just changed it to `fwrite($fp, "POST https://example.com/catalog/controller/sockets/receive_data.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");` but have the same result as before.

Comment: That wont work, why are you extending the controller here ?
What about putting this index.php code inside a simple php file inside server root (server_root/recieve.php) and POST to https://example.com/recieve.php

Comment: In secrity and scalability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to make a connection via localhost and find not used port:

**socket_post.php**

```
<?php
class ControllerSocketsSocketPost extends Controller {
public function index() {
    header('Content-type: text/plain');

    $fp = fsockopen('localhost', 8080, $errno, $errstr, 30);

      if ($errno) {
        echo "ERRNO: $errno \r\n";
        echo "ERRSTR: $errstr \r\n";
      } else {

        $vars = array(
            'mail_to' => 'your@email.com',
            'message' => 'Hello world'
        );

        $content = http_build_query($vars);

        if ($fp) {
            fwrite($fp, "POST /catalog/controller/sockets/receive_data.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "Host: localhost\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "Connection: close\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "\r\n");

            fwrite($fp, $content);
            fclose($fp); // Complete script execution without waiting for the response
            echo "Done\r\n";
/*
            while (!feof($fp)) { // Wait for response if socket connection not closed yet
                echo fread($fp, 1024);
            }
*/
        }
      }
   }
}
```

And receiver should be just simple php script, idk how to handle OpenCart controller in this case:

**receive_data.php**

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
sleep(10);

mail($mail_to, 'Async PHP', $message);
```

Hope it will help to somebody.